# CheckMenuItems selections Javafx

Tags: javafx

I have three CheckMenuItems Items 1,2 and 3. I`m trying to set it so that one item can be selected at a time. So far i have been able to do this using the item.setSelected() in each item. Although this works it does not prevent the item currently in use from being deselected. How can i prevent this.

Comment: Don't you need a [`RadioMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioMenuItem.html)?

Comment: Thanks yeah i need to use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [RadioMenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioMenuItem.html)

```
Menu menu = new Menu("Radio Button Menu");

ToggleGroup myToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

RadioMenuItem itemOne = RadioMenuItemBuilder.create().toggleGroup(myToggleGroup).text("itemOne").build();
RadioMenuItem itemTwo = RadioMenuItemBuilder.create().toggleGroup(myToggleGroup).text("itemTwo").selected(true).build();

menu.getItems().add(itemOne);
menu.getItems().add(itemTwo);
```